# Polymer core-icon is not displaying on Firefox but on Chrome

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am facing a strange problem with Polymer core-icon. Below is my snippet:

```html
...
...
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-icons/iconsets/social-icons.html">
...
...
<post-card id="card-1">
  <div>Something in bold!</div>
  <h2>My first post-card element with core-icon</h2>
  <p>Core-icon is not rendering properly on Firefox...Please help!</p>
  <core-icon class="large-icon" icon="android"></core-icon>
</post-card>
```

And my post-card element looks like this:

```html
...
<div class="card-header" layout horizontal center>
  <content select="img"><img src="images/{{imgsrc}}" alt="" /></content>
  <content select="h2">{{heading}}</content>
</div>
<content select="p">{{para}}</content>
<content></content>
...
```

When I am running the above in Chrome the icon is rendering fine but on Firefox the icon is only flashing once and then disappears!

Rest of the content placed inside  insertion point are rendering OK on both browsers.

Following screenshot shows what I have on different browsers:

[image]

For creating post-card element I have referred the following link:
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/tutorial/step-2.html

I have started with Polymer recently. Looking forward to expert help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I got it to work!

It is the CSS which was not working the similar way in Chrome and Firefox. I had a background property #ffffff set in the CSS for post-card element which surprisingly was overlapping the icons on Firefox! When I set the bacground property to "none" icons appear fine in both browsers!

```css
:host {
  /*background: #ffffff;*/
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
  @include respond-to(handhelds) { width: 100%; clear:both; display:block !important; background:#ccff00;}
  @include respond-to(medium-screens) { width: 30%; float:left; background:#dddddd; }
  @include respond-to(wide-screens) { width:25%; float:left; }
  margin:5px;
}
```

NB: I tried the following too:

```css
1. removed the line background: #ffffff;
2. background: transparent
```

but none of the above worked until I set it as

```css
background: none;
```

I got screwed up completely and had no idea that a background color can make life miserable!